# Dropdown list in yii from other controller

Tags: list, drop-down-menu, controller, yii

I want list all objects of my model, and write to file the id of selected model. Using SiteController I render my page but what model I shall use?

```
$models = myModel::model()->findAll();
$list = CHtml::listData($models, 'id', 'name');

echo CHtml::dropDownList( ???? , $select, $list);
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say list all objects?  I'm guessing your model has more than one piece of data, so what do you want to show in your dropdown?  Are you getting a specific error?  The first argument to dropDownList is just a string, and should be the name that will be used in the generated HTML for the input field.  In any case, this question needs a lot of clarification before anything can be answered.

Comment: sorry, CHtml::activeDropDownList

Comment: I want to show name, but I also want to write 'id' of selected model to variable

Comment: Okay, so what's not working?  This looks like it should be fine?

Comment: echo CHtml::activeDropDownList($variableToWhichIwantWriteSelectedId, $selectedElement, $list); and I'll get Fatal Error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I get what you're trying to do, You're talking about two models. Like tbl_product => Product and tbl_category => Category.

For demonstration purpose: Say, you want to create a new product and every product must belong to a category, then you might make use of the active dropdown. Using code similar to yours, you can say:

```
$category = Category::model()->findAll();
$list = CHtml::listData($category, 'id', 'name');
```

An important thing to note is that CHtml::activeDropDownList() expects different kinds of arguments. The main difference between it and CHtml::dropDownList() is that activeDropDownList( is tied to a Model while dropDownList() isn't.

```
public static string activeDropDownList(CModel $model, string $attribute, array $data, array $htmlOptions=array ())

public static string dropDownList(string $name, string $select, array $data, array $htmlOptions=array ())
```

So, using the example, assuming our Product model has a field called category_id, then the dropdown list would be generated using either:

```
CHtml::activeDropDownList($model, 'category_id', $list);
```

or if you've created an Activeform object like this:

```
$form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm');
```

then you could create the dropDown list like this:

```
$form->dropDownList($model, 'category_id', $list);
```

Where $model would be the Product model.

I hope this has been helpful.

Comment: Yii, yes it is. Thank you!